# Get first date record from multiple records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data-set. I have multiple records for days. I need only the most recent record for the each day.

```
eid     aid     eDate                   lastUpdated
8963    3493689 2018-03-29 00:00:00.000 2018-03-29 09:53:03.080
8964    3493689 2018-03-29 00:00:00.000 2018-03-30 08:44:04.087
9127    3493689 2018-04-06 00:00:00.000 2018-03-30 11:00:47.450
9008    3493689 2018-04-06 00:00:00.000 2018-03-29 11:56:51.900
```

Desired outout is only 2 records (eid 8964 & 9127). So basically one record for the day. 
Query is

```
select eid, aid, eventdate as eDate, lastUpdated from tbl_appt  where aid = '3493689'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row\_Number() Over Partition - Easier Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674812/row-number-over-partition-easier-way)

Answer (score 4):

You can partition data on eDate and get the first row for each partition.
if You want to pick the newest record, you need to use `order by eventdate desc`, and if you want the oldest, use `order by eventdate asc`

```
;with ct as (
    select eid, aid, eventdate as eDate, lastUpdated
    , RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY cast(eventdate as date) order by eventdate desc)
    from tbl_appt  
    where aid = '3493689'
)
select eid, aid, eDate, lastUpdated
from ct
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple NOT EXISTS will do:

```
select t.eid, t.aid, t.eventdate as eDate, t.lastUpdated 
from tbl_appt t 
where t.aid = '3493689'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tbl_appt
  where aid = t.aid and eventdate = t.eventdate and lastUpdated > t.lastUpdated
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5bc53a9cc5488e7c672027f88fb57df9).
Results:

```
>  eid |     aid | eDate                   | lastUpdated        
> ---: | ------: | :------------------     | :------------------
> 8964 | 3493689 | 2018-03-29 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-30 08:44:04.087
> 9127 | 3493689 | 2018-04-06 00:00:00.000 | 2018-03-30 11:00:47.450
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE (eid,     aid ,    eDate  , lastUpdated)
AS
(
SELECT 8963, 3493689,'2018-03-29 00:00:00.000','2018-03-29 09:53:03.080' UNION ALL
SELECT 8964, 3493689,'2018-03-29 00:00:00.000','2018-03-30 08:44:04.087' UNION ALL
SELECT 9127, 3493689,'2018-04-06 00:00:00.000','2018-03-30 11:00:47.450' UNION ALL
SELECT 9008, 3493689,'2018-04-06 00:00:00.000','2018-03-29 11:56:51.900' 
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
select      eid, 
            aid, 
            eDate as eDate, 
            lastUpdated,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY eDate ORDER BY lastUpdated DESC) AS ltst
from CTE  
     )dt WHERE ltst =1
   AND  aid = '3493689'
```